# Function not found

Tags: python, postgresql, function, class

I am trying to create a class that spins up a test db from sample JSON data using testing.postgresql. I want to call in 5 JSON files and create 5 tables that I can use for unit-testing operators and queries in airflow.

code so far is

```
import json
import decimal, datetime
import testing.postgresql
import psycopg2

class PostgresMock:
    
    with testing.postgresql.Postgresql() as postgresql:
        #engine = create_engine(postgresql.url())
        db = psycopg2.connect(**postgresql.dsn())

        #load Json file with dummy data
        def load_data(self):
            with open(self) as f:
                data=json.load(f)
            return data
        
        #build create statement from sql file
        def create_sql(self):
            # Find all keys
            keys = []
            for row in data:
                for key in row.keys():
                    if key not in keys:
                        keys.append(key)

            create_statement=("""CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE({0});""".format(",\n  ".join(map(lambda key: "{0} VARCHAR".format(key), keys))))

            return  create_statement
        
        #build insert statement
        def sql_insert(data):
            for row in data:
                print ("""INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES({0});""".format(
        ",".join(map(lambda key: "'{0}'".format(row[key]) if key in row else "NULL", keys))))
         
        #create handler for test db and insert 
        def handler(postgresql):
            conn = psycopg2.connect(**postgresql.dsn())
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(create_sql(file))
            for statement in sql_insert(data):
                try:
                    cursor.execute(f'{statement}')
                    conn.commit()
                except psycopg2.Error as errorMsg:
                    print(errorMsg)
                    conn.rollback()
            cursor.close()
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
            
         # Use `handler()` on initialize database
    PostgresqlMock = testing.postgresql.PostgresqlFactory(cache_initialized_db=True,
                                                  on_initialized=handler)
```

Getting the error

```
name 'create_sql' is not defined
```

Comment: Why are you opening a with-block in a class definition and trying to define methods inside it?

Comment: I hadn't realised I was doing that. I had this in a jupyter notebook and trying to piece it all together in one class.

Comment: What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error `name 'create_sql' is not defined` because you're referencing the function inside the object without using the self argument.

If you want to reference an object function within another object function you can do so, by adding `self` to the function call as well as the function in which you are calling it.

Like so:

```py
def handler(self, postgresql): # changed a line here
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**postgresql.dsn())
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(self.create_sql(file)) # changed a line here
    for statement in sql_insert(data):
        try:
            cursor.execute(f'{statement}')
            conn.commit()
        except psycopg2.Error as errorMsg:
            print(errorMsg)
            conn.rollback()
    cursor.close()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```